# Django serialization: AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field on serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following error,

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `devicedetails` on serializer `DISerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Device` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'Device' object has no attribute 'devicedetails'.

My models.py :-

```
class DeviceInfo(models.Model):
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    modelname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    username = models.TextField()
    password = EncryptedTextField()
    deviceinfo = models.ForeignKey(DeviceInfo, null=True)

class DeviceDetails(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializer.py :-

```
class DeviceInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceInfo
        fields = ("id", "vendor", "device_type", "modelname")

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ("name","username", "password", "deviceinfo")

class DeviceDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = DevieceDetails
         fields = ("device", "serial_number", "version")

class DISerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    deviceinfo = DeviceInfoSerializer(read_only=True)
    devicedetails = DeviceDetailsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ("name", "username", "password", "deviceinfo", "devicedetails")
```

views.py :-

```
def list(self, request):
    list = Device.objects.all()
    serializer = DISerializer(list, many=True)
```

Comment: Your `DISerializer.devicedetails` attribute does not have a `source` parameter specified. This means the default behavior will be invoked - looking for an attribute by that name on the `Device` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename `devicedetails` field to `devicedetails_set`. Automatically generated reverse name for relation padded with `_set`:

```
devicedetails_set = DeviceDetailsSerializer(many=True)
```

or use `related_name` on `DeviceDetails's` `device` field:

```
device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='devicedetails')
```

From the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations):

> If you have not set a related name for the reverse relationship, you'll need to use the automatically generated related name in the fields argument. For example: track_set